# Java - I can't print on the same line (I'm not using println)

Tags: java

This seems to be a common question but I couldn't find the solution to my problem. I started learning Java very recently so I barely know the basic.

My professor gave an assignment where I have to write my name using asterisks. I did that using only one 'System.out.print' and it's very disorganized and confusing. So I tried this:

```
public class teste2
{ public static void main (String[] args)
{ 
  String BR = "*****   ***** \n*    *  *     *\n*    *  *    *\n*****  *****  \n*     * *     *\n*     * *     *\n******  ";

  String U = "*     *\n*     *\n*     *\n*     *\n*     *\n*    *\n*******";

  System.out.print (BR + U);
}
```

It works but they are in different lines, and I need it to be in just 1 line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you do have "\n"s in the strings. Do you know what those are?

Comment: Yes, I need them to make the letters. I guess they're the ones getting on the way?

Comment: `"\n"` is the escape sequence for a newline, meaning it places a line break in the output.

Comment: "\n" are newline characters, which when printed, move the cursor to the next line.

Comment: If you're trying to align multiple premade formatted characters made up of stars horizontally, you can't do it like this. That's not an easy problem to solve.

Comment: Andy, I know I need more lines. The problem is that the U is below the BR if I do it like that. I could do it all together, which I've done already, but it is really cluttered.

Comment: @imveryconfused To do what you're trying to do, you're going have to take each line of BR and U individually, take the newlines off the end of each line, then glue each line together. Start with trying to glue two single lines together, then work up to BR and U.

Comment: @imveryconfused Just a heads up, I made a programming challenge based on your question. It may be worth checking out: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/158354/31224

Answer (score 0):

Ok, like you have probably seen by the comments on your question, many people say that you use '\n' wheras this says the java console to start a new line. So to do this in just one like you have to write each line after line, so to do this better I would first of all make all the letters. For this you could use individual Arrays.
Eg:

```
public class teste2 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           // This creates T
           String[] t = new String[6];
           t[0] = "*******";
           for(int i = 1; i < t.length; i++) t[i] = "   *   ";

           // This creates E
           String[] e = new String[6];
           e[0] = "*******";
           e[1] = "*      ";
           e[2] = "****   ";
           e[3] = "*      ";
           e[4] = "*      ";
           e[5] = "*******";

           // This creates S
           String[] s = new String[6];
           s[0] = " ******";
           s[1] = "*      ";
           s[2] = " ***** ";
           s[3] = "      *";
           s[4] = "      *";
           s[5] = "****** ";

           // Now you need to print this.
           for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(t[i]+"\t"+e[i]+"\t"+s[i]+"\t"+t[i]);
           }
           // This should be it.
           // You can still optimize the code and make everything in one
           // line but I think this is WAY better to read and better to
           // use as you can also use letters like the T more often.
           // BTW: this is TEST so not your name ;)
           // You need to program your own letters :)
     }
}
```

If this does not help sorry. But I would do it like this as this is easy to implement and to use.